# Logstash cannot connect to Elasticsearch on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, connection, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm having trouble connecting Logstash to Elasticsearch.

I have installed ELK stack on kubernetes using helm. Every pod is running and is in ready state.
Elasticsearch and kibana are perfectly fine (i.e connecting properly). The problem is with logstash not able to identify Elasticsearch to establish connection.

Find the screenshot of error below:

[image: here's the problem]

[image: as you can see everything is running fine]

Please help to suggest proper solution for the same.

Comment: You are trying to reach it by _http://elasticsearch:9200/_. I don't know if the DNS knows about that name. Did you add a service to elastic? If so, you can try using the URL of the service: [service].[namespace].svc.cluster.local. KubeDNS knows that endpoint. My fluentbit daemonset uses:

        env:
        - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: "elasticsearch-depl-es-http.elastic-system.svc.cluster.local". Let me know if it works, and ill write an answer you can accept

Comment: hello @MartW thank you for your reply. i'm gonna be honest with you i'm still not that good with kubernetes, but no i didn't add any services since i thought helm took care of that, but i understand the problem, i just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Let me edit my asnwer then

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl get services --namespace=elk`? And please just paste the actual terminal output inside of backticks (`) instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following
https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/exporting-kubernetes-logs-to-elasticsearch-using-fluent-bit-758e8de606af

In step 3, the fluentbit DaemonSet is deployed. Here, the `env` variable `FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST` is modified to `elasticsearch.default.svc.cluster.local` according to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#srv-records in the format of `[srv].[namespace].srv.cluster.local`. That connection string is known by the Kubernetes DNS.

So change your environment variable to the 'Kubernetes DNS' format

By following the ECK tutorial, you should have a service already, which you can get by executing `kubectl get services -n [namespace]` or `kubectl get services -A`

Comment: thank you !! i appreciate it a lot i'll look at the links and try to resolve the problem